# How to convert this code from Oracle to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, oracle

I'm trying to convert this code from Oracle database to Postgresql, can someone help me with that?

```sql
WITH cycles AS
(
    SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (child_node_id, ',') AS path, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH ( CASE WHEN child_node_id < CONNECT_BY_ROOT child_node_id THEN child_node_id END, ','
) AS less_path
FROM alf_child_ASSOC
WHERE CONNECT_BY_ROOT parent_node_id = child_node_id
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE parent_node_id = PRIOR child_node_id
)

SELECT *
FROM cycles
WHERE LTRIM (less_path, ',') IS NULL ;
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a recursive query, but I hardly know anything about Oracle... Maybe the manual can help you out: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE prev AS (
        SELECT alf_child_ASSOC.child_node_id, 1 AS depth, array[child_node_id] as seen, false as cycle
        FROM alf_child_ASSOC
        UNION ALL
        SELECT alf_child_ASSOC.child_node_id, prev.depth + 1, seen || alf_child_ASSOC.child_node_id as seen,
            alf_child_ASSOC.child_node_id = any(seen) as cycle
        FROM prev
        INNER JOIN alf_child_ASSOC on prev.child_node_id = parent_node_id
        AND prev.cycle = false
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM prev
    WHERE cycle = true;
```

Exemple of output:

```
 child_node_id | depth |       seen        | cycle
---------------+-------+-------------------+-------
        749254 |     2 | {749254,749254}   | t
        749675 |     2 | {749675,749675}   | t
        754208 |     2 | {754208,754208}   | t
```

Comment: You could also use the new `CYCLE` option to detect cycles.

Comment: This option is available on postgresql 14, I have postgresql 9.3, but yes this new option could have saved me a headache :)

Comment: Then you should upgrade as soon as possible. Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your Oracle query from a hierarchical query to a recursive query in the form:

```sql
WITH cycles (path, root_id, child_node_id) AS (
  SELECT ',' || child_node_id,
         parent_node_id AS root_id,
         child_node_id
  FROM   alf_child_assoc
  WHERE  parent_node_id > child_node_id
UNION ALL
  SELECT c.path || ',' || a.child_node_id,
         c.root_id,
         a.child_node_id
  FROM   cycles c
         INNER JOIN alf_child_assoc a
         ON (c.child_node_id = a.parent_node_id)
  WHERE  a.parent_node_id != c.root_id
)
SELECT path
FROM   cycles
WHERE  child_node_id = root_id
```

*Oracle db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=10e2f47f51a12463bfc753e3658caeaa)*

Then all you need to do to convert to PostgreSQL is to add the `RECURSIVE` keyword:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cycles (path, root_id, child_node_id) AS (
  SELECT ',' || child_node_id,
         parent_node_id AS root_id,
         child_node_id
  FROM   alf_child_assoc
  WHERE  parent_node_id > child_node_id
UNION ALL
  SELECT c.path || ',' || a.child_node_id,
         c.root_id,
         a.child_node_id
  FROM   cycles c
         INNER JOIN alf_child_assoc a
         ON (c.child_node_id = a.parent_node_id)
  WHERE  a.parent_node_id != c.root_id
)
SELECT path
FROM   cycles
WHERE  child_node_id = root_id
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE alf_child_assoc (
  child_node_id  NUMERIC(10,0),
  parent_node_id NUMERIC(10,0)
);

INSERT INTO alf_child_assoc (child_node_id, parent_node_id) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO alf_child_assoc (child_node_id, parent_node_id) VALUES (3, 2);
INSERT INTO alf_child_assoc (child_node_id, parent_node_id) VALUES (1, 3);
```

Outputs:

> | PATH |
> | --- |
> | ,1,2,3 |

*PostgreSQL db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=db967b4fb92868ebad220b9d366f84fb)*

Comment: This query does not give me any results, but I found a solution: see the answer bellow

Comment: @SébastienVallet Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72727679/edit) your question to include a [MRE] with some sample data. Just stating "This query does not give any results" is not constructive as it gives us nothing to debug against; whereas if you provide some sample data and then state "this query does not give the expected output for this data" is a constructive statement and we can then provide you with an improved solution.